# Restrict / Block Directory Based on IP Address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip-address, ip-restrictions

Trying to block directory access from everyone except 1 IP address.  This .htaccess code blocks access but it blocks access to everything including images, css, etc.  What do I need to change?

`RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XX\.XXX$

RewriteRule ^hidedirectory(.*)$ http://site.com/ [R,L]`

Anyone accessing mysite.com/hidedirectory except me should redirect to mysite.com.  Is there a better, more secure way to do this including something like an http response code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way is to do this in your `.conf` file:

```
<Directory /hidedirectory>
 options -Indexes
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
</Directory>
```

This will deny everythig like your rewrite rules.
But since you want to allow access to images/css etc...

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XX\.XXX$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^hidedirectory(.*)$ http://site.com/ [R,L]
```

Add any other extensions into `(?:jpe?g|png|gif|css)` suffixed by a `|`(or).